# Laravel Call to a member function send() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to send a mail using my laravel controller, a very simple mail which is sent in my localhost with no problems but once in server I get this error :

```
20170325T153701: /public/index.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function send() on a non-object in /public/index.php on line 56 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function send() on a non-object in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 107
```

The browser only shows a 500 error, the error is only seen in my error log. Here is the code used to send the mail

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; // just to say I'm calling it
    $v_code = str_random(30);
    $mail_content = array('code' => $v_code);


    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['pass']),
    ]);

    if ($user) {
        Mail::send('User::mail.verifyMail', $mail_content, function ($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])
                ->subject('Verify your email address');
        });
```

Comment: may be a silly question, but: did you install all the dependencies through composer?

Comment: ArSeN yes of course, composer install, composer update and dump-autoload :)

Comment: and as said, this works on local so how it would be without an install :)

Comment: Just guessing here :) Did you remember to also set the proper environment ( see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#environment-configuration ) and also made sure all the settings are there for your chosen environment? (guessing you are using a different one for your server)

Comment: No worries about that cause this is my 7th client website, using same env, same laravel & php versions, same server. all others work with no errors ! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was on casting the $name with a (string). I don't know why, but anytime the name contains a space (' ') it simply fails and the $name is considered as null. Thus, a (string) resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `use` line.

```
\Mail::send('User::mail.verifyMail', $mail_content, function ($message) use ($data) {
      $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])
              ->subject('Verify your email address');
});
```

Comment: How would I access the email and name if I remove the use .. this is a basic php "use" method .....

Comment: I have used that `\` in front of `Mail`